# Is there anyway we can give two conditions in Scalatest using ShouldMatchers

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scalatest

How can I do something like this? Check for two conditions while testing

```
// b is Option[Array[Int]]
b should be ('empty) || b.get should be ('empty)
```

I want to do it using ShouldMatchers instead of assert, since ShouldMatchers is part of scalatest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
val b: Option[Array[Int]] = ???
b should (be ('empty) or be (Some(Array.empty[Int]))
```

See this section of the scalatest manual: [Logical Expressions](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#logicalExpressions)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it should be `('empty)` instead of just `'empty`. It gives syntax error.